# Multiplying fields in Sequelize select

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following code snippet:

```
    const buys = await Buy.findAll({
      where: {
        account_id: req.params.id,
      },
      attributes: ['id', 'account_id', 'buy_value', 'quantity'],
    });

    return res.json(buys);
```

Which returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "account_id": 3,
    "buy_value": "49521.00",
    "quantity": 2
}
```

I would like to return within the same JSON, a `test_field` that multiplies the `buy_value` and `quantity` fields. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Sequelize.literal like this:

```
const buys = await Buy.findAll({
      where: {
        account_id: req.params.id,
      },
      attributes: ['id', 'account_id', 'buy_value', 'quantity', [Sequelize.literal('buy_value*quantity'), 'test_field']],
    });
```